# Does anyone have a C# implementation of the Barone Adesi Whaley options pricing model?

Tags: options

Thanks. Can't seem to find it through google. Worst case, if you can provide me the code in Java or C++ I can convert it to C#.

Comment: For your worst case: it's available in [QuantLib](http://quantlib.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.1-1/classQuantLib_1_1BaroneAdesiWhaleyApproximationEngine.html) which you can use from C#.

Comment: I know my way around C# libraries and I'm better than most. If you provide a link to the formula, I can write one for you.

Comment: Would you like to provide some reference to a documentation of the model? Thanks!

Comment: @JimBeam, just a heads up.  Writing mathematical code is a job not to be taken lightly. THere are 100s of ways to mess it via loss of precision or not accounting for NaN's.  If you don't have experince with working on BLAS, QL or LAPACK then its not soemthing you should write and put into production if you can find a well testing implementation.  its not as simple as taking a math equation and writing an iterative solver for it.

Comment: @cholida It's only as difficult as you perceive it to be :) I've been working with C# for 10+ years now, this is not my first rodeo.

Comment: Here is the formula: https://quanto.inria.fr/pdf_html/apamer_doc/index.html I am most interested in American Options under section 1.1

Comment: @JimBeam, there was no offense intended.  But this statement "Its only as difficult as you perceive it to be", is just plain foolish. Writing mathematical code is like writing cryptography. Its something that alot programmers think they can do and the problem is that even if they get something that looks like its working its hard to know how robust your solution is  until if falls apart on you:)

I'll stick by my assertion that this is something that is best left to those who have done it many times before if the code will be used in production.  As a learning exercise, by all means go ahead:)

Comment: @JimBeam Please keep it nice. You don't have to agree but the point is valid. I've made a small edit to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The Quantlib.net C# port has a native C# version.  Get the [code from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qlnet/), unzip it and checkout:

```
path\QuantLib\QLNet-sources-1.0.0.zip\QLNet\Pricingengines\vanilla\Baroneadesiwhaleyengine.cs
```

To be honest, its proably worth your time to learn the library than to extract the implementation.  its very common in the industry and there are a bunch of stubble interactions around date handling that makes it hard to just use a specific implementation without using the entire library.